# Logger.getLogger("Classname".class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

Tags: java, multithreading

```
try{
///
}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(*"Classname"*.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

I'm beginer and when i saw a project then it have a class use Thread , Try-catch.

Line 5 what's mean?  Please help me.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Logger.getLogger&oq=Logger.getLogger&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0l4.232j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Line 5 allows you to get an instance of a logger and then log a message with the given Level (severe) containing the exception's (ex) stacktrace.
Check javadoc of the used classes for further details.